# rxjs why does behaviour subject when piped triggered with next()

Tags: rxjs

I have read the tutorial from this link https://magarcia.io/2019/02/18/bloc-pattern-with-react-hooks
and i just dont understand how the search query to the API is triggered when _query.next is called with new search terms

see below code.

```
export class SearchBloc {
  private _results$: Observable<string[]>;
  private _query$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor(private api: API) {
    **this._results$ = this._query$.pipe(
      switchMap((query) => {
        return observableFrom(this.api.search(query));
      })
    );**
  get results$(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this._results$;
  }
}

const SearchInput = () => {
  const searchBloc = useContext(SearchContext);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    searchBloc.query.next(query);
  }, [searchBloc, query]);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="Search"
      value={query}
      onChange={({ target }) => setQuery(target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

Assuming that searchblock was put in the context, and during input change the query which is a behaviour subject is assigned a new value with next();
how or why does the api query executes?
I guess I did not understand the line with

**this._results$ = this._query$.pipe(
switchMap((query) => {**

so maybe the question is, how did the pipe worked? did it create a method callback that will execute when next is called? and what is the assignment to result mean?

anyone that can help me make sense of it is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

It creates a stream of 5 numbers. Then it creates a second stream which is defined as a stream that has all the same numbers as the first one, only each number is incremented.

```ts
const numberStream$ = of(1,2,3,4,5);

const numbersPlus1$ = numberStream$.pipe(
  map(v => v + 1)
);

numbersPlus1$.subscribe(console.log);
```

If you subscribe to `numberStream$` you should expect to get 1,2,3,4,5.
If you subscribe to `numbersPlus1$` you should expect to get 2,3,4,5,6.

---

Here we do the same thing with a `Subject`. Of course, unlike `of(1,2,3,4,5)`, a subject lets you create a stream imperatively. Whenever I call `.next` on a subject, I'm saying "Make this value the next emission in this subject's stream."

```ts
const numberSubject$ = new Subject<number>();

const numbersPlus1$ = numberSubject$.pipe(
  map(v => v + 1)
);

numbersPlus1$.subscribe(console.log);

numberSubject$.next(1);
numberSubject$.next(2);
numberSubject$.next(3);
numberSubject$.next(4);
numberSubject$.next(5);
```